# "Lived" vs "lived in."

Tags: sentence

> Erin no longer recognized her home. She felt as if she had entered a
>   recent battlefield, or a recycling center. It could have been
>   anything—anything except the place she lived (in).

Do I have to add the final **in** in cases like the one above?

Comment: Have you visited the ELL Q&A? ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better asked on ELL.


Comment: @Kris OK, I agree with a migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, please add the *in* or add a *where*

- anything except the place she lived in.
- anything except the place where she lived.

How about

> Erin no longer recognized the place. She felt as if she had entered a recent battlefield, or a recycling center. It could have been anything—anything except her home.

Comment: I'd say "she had lived in."

Comment: then she no longer lived in it

Comment: But isn't that what he is trying to say?

Comment: I second Noah. It should be "she had lived in."

Comment: Erin's house was just hit by an earthquake. She'll still live there afterwards.

Comment: that is what I read too. It is still her home, if she clean it up she still lives in it.

Answer (score 1):

The verb 'live' is usually intransitive; AHD lists three transitive senses:

> v.tr.
>
> 1. To spend or pass (one's life). [lived a dog's life] [cognate object]
> 2. To go through; experience: lived a nightmare.
> 3. To practice in one's life: live one's beliefs.

However, the range of allowable objects is severely restricted. Places, buildings, most conditions (*lived a catastrophe) are not used.

Regarding complementation, the situation is different with the French word *habiter* - though one says j'habite au Maroc, one also says j'habite une maison.

One must also recognise the direct-object-like 'adverbial objectives':

> He lived an obscure peasant; he died a hero.

Comment: How does this analysis answer the question asked?

Comment: OP is essentially asking for the licensed complementation patterns of 'live'. Can one say 'He lived DO' or not? And what are the restrictions on the actual DOs allowed? Must one use 'He lived PP' instead? He broadens his query to 'cases like', which broadening is obviously open to interpretation. I added the DO-like structure using an adverbial objective to show that (Subject + Verb + Noun Group) strings do not necessarily even have a DO.

Comment: Whoosh is the sound of this going right over people's head :) but I'm sure you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at the other answers I'm taking a swing at this.

"The place **where** she lived" is correct without "in."
In the following case:
"The place she lived in" is correct because it does not have "where" as a preface.

The place where she lived = this house is where she **lived** most of her life.
or

The place she lived in = the home she **lived in** was messy.

This would be true in other cases as well:

I live in this house, This is the house I **live in**; or This is the house **where** I live.

I lived **here** last year. I **lived in** this house last year, or This is **where** I lived last year.

He lives in a shack. That is the shack **where** he lives, or That is the shack he **lives in.**

Conversely: Does he live **there**? Is that the house he **lives in**? Is that **where** he lives?

It seems that location is the key factor in deciding whether to use "in" to indicate having a place to dwell full time. When the words "here," "where," or "there" indicate a place of domain, "in" is not necessary. "This" does not qualify as a place indicator for this purpose.

I'm going to take a wild swing and say your sentence is not complete. When I first looked at it I thought it was fine without "in", but you wrote `"the place she lived"` In that case your sentence needs "in" **but the sentence would end in a preposition**, and that is a no-no. So insert the word `"where"` into your sentence to make it grammatically correct, so you have `"the place where she lived."` You don't need `"in"` and **the sentence no longer ends with a preposition.**

Comment: Yeah, I finally decided for "the place where she lived."  Ending a sentence with a preposition is grammatically incorrect or just a sign of bad writing?

Comment: It's not necessarily incorrect, but, when I see a preposition at the end like that, I'll often at least make an attempt to improve the sentence. If an improvement proves to be elusive, maybe the sentence is just fine as-is.

Comment: It is an indication one is not proficient with the language. It is often written by students in schools from high school down, but when it appears in college papers, the professors will devalue the writing. Whether that matters depends on the class. In fiction or other writing for public consumption, no professional writer would allow it in anything other than stylized dialog or a quote.

Comment: One can always change a preposition's location. You can use "in which" "by which" or "for which" and other forms that move the preposition away from the end. Since I learned that form, I have never ended a sentence with a preposition except as dialog in fiction. Some cases are "Do you want to go in?" and "I'll stop by." This is because we don't write in the same manner that we speak. Speech is less formal.